# inspect.isabstract returns false on an abstract class

Tags: python

I need to determine if a class is abstract. The documentation of the inspect module indicates that inspect.isabstract should do this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html

However, in python 3.8.6 I find that inspect.isabstract doesn't work the way I expect.

For instance, the following code, copied with slight modifications from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/test_inspect.py:

```
import inspect
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class AbstractClassExample(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

# Fails here
assert inspect.isabstract(AbstractClassExample)
```

The above code does work in python 2.7, but fails in python 3.8.6. Is this a bug in python 3.8.6, or did something change in how inspect.isabstract works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using metaclasses incorrectly (in the Python 2 way, which is silently ignored on Python 3), so your class isn't actually an `ABC` (`isabstract` is reporting this correctly). Change:

```
class AbstractClassExample(object):  # There is no need to inherit from object on Py3 (it's automatic)
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta  # This means nothing on Py3, it's just some random class attribute
```

to:

```
class MyABC(metaclass=ABCMeta):  # How you explicitly declare your metaclass on Py3
```

or just inherit from `ABC`, which is an otherwise empty class that has `ABCMeta` as a metaclass, which, unlike explicitly specifying a metaclass, allows you to use the same syntax in Python 2 and Python 3:

```
from abc import ABC

class MyABC(ABC):  # Inheriting from a class with the desired metaclass is simplest
```

Comment: This still doesn't work even on Python 3.8. Just try to call `isabstract(MyABC)` where `MyABC` is declared as `class MyABC(ABC): pass`

Comment: @PeterZaitcev: You have to include an `abstractmethod`, as the OP is doing. I omitted the body of the classes for brevity; it wouldn't just be `pass`, because if it was, then it wouldn't be abstract, since it would have no abstract methods.